# An inequality similar to Poincare inequality using $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$

Tags: integration, inequality, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, estimation

[image]

I am trying to use the same argument for [Poincare inequality](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lecture4.pdf) but fail to have any progress.